# Сортировка массива по своим правилам

Tags: javascript, массивы, сортировка

Как отсортировать массив по возрастанию не учитывая первые три символа (210)

````
const arr = ['210-10-09-10', '210-03-210-08-11', '210-09-08-05', '210-01-04-02']```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
function compare(a, b) {
  var a_ = a.substring(3);
  var b_ = b.substring(3);
  if (a_<b_) {
    return -1;
  }
  if (a_>b_) {
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
const arr = ['210-10-09-10', '210-03-210-08-11', '210-09-08-05', '210-01-04-02'];
var sortedarray = arr.sort(compare);
```

Вывод: `["210-01-04-02", "210-03-210-08-11", "210-09-08-05", "210-10-09-10"]`

Тест: `const arr2 = ['000-10-09-10', '210-03-210-08-11', '210-09-08-05', '213-01-04-02'];`
Вывод: `["213-01-04-02", "210-03-210-08-11", "210-09-08-05", "000-10-09-10"]`

Comment: Думаю это можно было бы завернуть в фрагмент кода.

Answer (score 0):

Можно так

```js
const arr = ['210-10-09-10', '210-03-210-08-11', '210-09-08-05', '210-01-04-02'];

arr.sort((a, b) =>  a.substring(3).localeCompare(b.substring(3)));

console.log(arr)
```